# "Command not found" for no reason, even when it doesn't try to run a command

Tags: bash, osx

This is the errors I get when I try to run my script

```
~bin/killp: line 7: [[ menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 11: [[ menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 11:  [[: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15: [[ menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15:  [[: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15:  [[ menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 19: conditional binary operator expected
~bin/killp: line 19: syntax error near `Dock'
~bin/killp: line 19: `if [[ $1 == Dock ]]; then'
```

This is what these lines look like

```
if [[ $1 == Desktop ]] || [[ $1 == Finder ]]; then
killall Finder
fi
```

The only difference is `Desktop` and `Finder`. `menubar` is the argument I am passing to the script, aka `$1`.

Comment: Show use the whole script. It looks like it's not executed by `bash`.

Comment: I have tried to specifically add "bash" before the script, and this (#!/bin/bash) is in the beginning.

Comment: Copy-paste the whole script.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error messages, your script probably has some hidden non-breaking space characters (e.g. you typed <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>)

e.g. the errors are really something like:

```
~bin/killp: line 7: [[@menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 11: [[@menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 11: @[[: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15: [[@menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15: @[[: command not found
~bin/killp: line 15: @[[@menubar: command not found
~bin/killp: line 19: conditional binary operator expected
~bin/killp: line 19: syntax error near `Dock'
~bin/killp: line 19: `if [[ $1 == Dock ]]; then' <-- Somewhere, not sure where.
```

Where I have replaced the invisible characters with @.

Comment: I also thought this, so I tried replacing all " [[" with " [[" (yes, the same thing). But I didn't think of the positions like you did. I will check if this is the case.

Comment: @DisplayName AIUI You need the spaces, but they need to be real spaces. What text editor are you using?

Comment: yeah of course I need the spaces. I replaced "(space)[[" with the same thing ((space) being " "). (There were spaces in my comment)  I use Sublime Text, I have had this problem very often, I don't know why I accidentally make faulty whitespaces.

Comment: My guess is shift + space.

Comment: @DisplayName, it seems to be the space *after* `[[`, so try replacing `/[[./` with `"[[ "`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience things like this are solved by looking a line or two up in the code and finding something I screwed up.

I just typed out what you gave on a Mac using vim (used echo instead of killall) and it ran just fine and this:

```
$ more test.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $1 == Desktop ]] || [[ $1 == Finder ]]; then
    echo "Finder"
fi
```

On a Windows box running cygwin:

```
petro@<blur> ~
$ ./test.sh

petro@<blur> ~
$ ./test.sh stuffing

petro@<blur> ~
$ ./test.sh Finder
Finder
```

So the code as written seems fine, your problem is likely above it.

Comment: Non-breaking spaces don't paste correctly into editing forms in most browsers.

Comment: Yeah, but I really didn't see how he could keep getting that. I guess that's what happens when one abandons Gods Own Editor(s) (vi/emacs) in favor of those new fangled things. 
(J/K)